# How can I integrate a Line Chart Viewer in PyGame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygame, pygame-surface

I have an AI for a game in Pygame and I want to create a chart to follow the evolution.

I need only the Gen on X-axis and Points on the Y-axis.

I have tried this but I don't know how to make it fit on the surface in the game, and not pop out as an individual window(which will eventually stop the game)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(Generation=[], Points=[])
    plt.title('Points per Generation')
    plt.xlabel('Generation')
    plt.ylabel('Points')
    plt.show()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to render and store the [`pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html) to a [Buffered Steam](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). This stream can be loaded into a  [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load):

```py
plot_stream = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(plot_stream, formatstr='png')
plot_stream.seek(0)

plot_surface = pygame.image.load(plot_stream, 'PNG')
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygame
import io

plt.plot(Generation=[], Points=[])
plt.title('Points per Generation')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Points')

plot_stream = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(plot_stream, formatstr='png')
plot_stream.seek(0)

pygame.init()
plot_surface = pygame.image.load(plot_stream, 'PNG')

window = pygame.display.set_mode(plot_surface.get_size())
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(plot_surface, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```